# Any standards on how to display changes in XML data files?

Tags: xml, delta

We're using XML to deliver vast amounts of data to clients. Presently, we deliver a full initialization record, then provide update files of any changes. However, the updates provide full replacement records if any element or attribute in the record changes. 
Clients have asked us for "true" deltas, delivering just the field that is new, along with the previous value. Are there any standards for how to do that in XML? The "new" seems straightforward - we can simply provide the new value using the existing tag. But the previous value is not as obvious. 
Before we create a new approach, are there any standards or good examples you've seen?

Answer (score 0):

There's a W3C Community Group on change tracking

https://www.w3.org/community/change/

but as far as I can see it is dormant.